# What is the best way to convert all controller params from camelCase to snake_case in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

As you already know, JSON naming convention advocates the use of camelCase and the Rails advocates the use of snake_case for parameter names.

What is the best way to convert all request's params to snake_case in a rails controller?

From this:

```
{
  ...
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "moreInfo":
  {
    "mealType": 2,
    "mealSize": 4,
    ...
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  ...
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "more_info":
  {
    "meal_type": 2,
    "meal_size": 4,
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 94):

When you’ve completed the steps below, `camelCase` param names submitted via JSON requests will be changed to `snake_case`.

For example, a JSON request param named `passwordConfirmation` would be accessed in a controller as `params[:password_confirmation]`

Create an initializer at `config/initializers/json_param_key_transform.rb`. This file is going to change the parameter parsing behaviour for JSON requests only (JSON requests must have the request header `Content-Type: application/json`).

Find your Rails version and choose the appropriate section below (find your Rails version in `Gemfile.lock`):

## For Rails 5 and 6

For Rails 5 and 6, to convert camel-case param keys to snake-case, put this in the initializer:

```rb
# File: config/initializers/json_param_key_transform.rb
# Transform JSON request param keys from JSON-conventional camelCase to
# Rails-conventional snake_case:
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:json] = lambda { |raw_post|
  # Modified from action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb
  data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)

  # Transform camelCase param keys to snake_case
  if data.is_a?(Array)
    data.map { |item| item.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore) }
  else
    data.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)
  end

  # Return data
  data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : { '_json': data }
}
```

## For Rails 4.2 (and maybe earlier versions)

For Rails 4.2 (and maybe earlier versions), to convert camel-case param keys to snake-case, put this in the initializer:

```rb
# File: config/initializers/json_param_key_transform.rb
# Transform JSON request param keys from JSON-conventional camelCase to
# Rails-conventional snake_case:
Rails.application.config.middleware.swap(
  ::ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ::ActionDispatch::ParamsParser,
  ::Mime::JSON => Proc.new { |raw_post|

    # Borrowed from action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb except for
    # data.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore) :
    data = ::ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)
    data = {:_json => data} unless data.is_a?(::Hash)
    data = ::ActionDispatch::Request::Utils.deep_munge(data)
    
    # Transform camelCase param keys to snake_case:
    data.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)

    data.with_indifferent_access
  }
)
```

## Final step for all Rails versions

Restart `rails server`.

Comment: Note that for this to work with jQuery, you must set `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: In Rails 5.0 ParamsParser interface will be changed. You only need `data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)` and `data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : {:_json => data}`. Refer https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b7ac0790682e0a56b406127891dfefc15a5eaa64/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L7

Comment: Got `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError: undefined method 'underscore' for :_json:Symbol` when Array is passed. You should skip :_json or use another container hash (i.e. `data = { '_container' => data }` then call deep_transform_keys).

Comment: This does not work in rails 5. `assert_index': No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::ParamsParser (RuntimeError)`

Comment: Rails 5.0 instructions added above in main answer.

Comment: In Rails 5.0, I believe you need to use `Mime[:json].symbol`

Comment: @Sorenly can you confirm what beta/rc version of Rails 5 this change is needed in?

Comment: @EliotSykes here you go https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/97ed810cfc15725a0856227fa9f9eb26930f16c8#diff-6a80fa5836403509e86a81c2117af391

Comment: @Sorenly much appreciated, thanks! Snippet updated for Rails 5.

Comment: @EliotSykes do you know similar solution for GET request?

Comment: @vladra what happens with GET requests when you try this? If you get errors, please provide details.

Comment: @EliotSykes during GET request the above code is not executed at all. I checked rails docs, and made an assumption that it is working only for POST or PUT/PATCH  http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/ParamsParser.html

Comment: @vladra It may be the Content-Type header is not set to application/json

Comment: `deep_transform_keys!` is deprecated for the `params` object in Rails 5. Instead, use `transform_keys!`, as in `params.transform_keys!(&:underscore)` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-transform_values-21))

Comment: @django09 Can you confirm this is an issue in the above code? In case its relevant to the deprecation, `data` is a `Hash`, not a `ActionController::Parameters` instance in the Rails 5 snippet.

Comment: Wouldn't calling `params.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)` in `before_action` in the base API controller also work in a Rails 4 app?

Comment: Hi @BrunoFacca, thanks, agree that approach would also work.

Comment: @BrunoFacca one problem w/calling it in a `before_action` is that the conversion happens later in the process. So if you want things like parameter wrapping (or even just logging the parameters) to work properly, you'll want to do it in an initializer. That's why I ended up here today :)

Comment: this solution did not handle query string parameters, instead I implemented a variation of another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023035/7573223)

Comment: This is not converting my values to snake case when I write request tests. Do my test environment not load the initalizers?

Answer (score 18):

Example with **camelCase to snake_case** in rails console

```
2.3.1 :001 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new({"firstName"=>"john", "lastName"=>"doe", "email"=>"john@doe.com"})
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"firstName"=>"john", "lastName"=>"doe", "email"=>"john@doe.com"} permitted: false>

2.3.1 :002 > params.transform_keys(&:underscore)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"john", "last_name"=>"doe", "email"=>"john@doe.com"} permitted: false>
```

source:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-transform_keys
http://apidock.com/rails/String/underscore

**UPDATE**:

If you have **nested attributes** and **Rails 6** you can do:

ActionController::Parameters convert to hash and then do deep transform:

`params.permit!.to_h.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }`
`params.permit!.to_h.deep_transform_values { |value| value.to_s.underscore }`

Please see:

http://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Hash/deep_transform_values http://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Hash/deep_transform_keys

Comment: I don't think this works in the case of nested parameters (e.g. `nested_model_attributes`)

Comment: @Matt Hello, thank you for your reply. If you use Rails 6 I think for nested attributes you can transform ActionController::Parameters to hash and then do deep transform attributes:

params.permit!.to_h.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }

or

params.permit!.to_h.deep_transform_values { |value| value.to_s.underscore }

Please see:

https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Hash/deep_transform_values
https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Hash/deep_transform_keys

Answer (score 15):

In **Rails 6.1** will be added `deep_transform_keys` to `ActionController::Parameters` so it enables you to make it as simple as:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :underscore_params!

  private

  def underscore_params!
    params.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)
  end
end
```

**Edit**

At the moment you can backport as follows:

```rb
module DeepTransformKeys
  def deep_transform_keys!(&block)
    @parameters.deep_transform_keys!(&block)
    self
  end
end

ActionController::Parameters.include(DeepTransformKeys)
```

Comment: NoMethodError
undefined method `deep_transform_keys!' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f9a5c044cc0>

Seems like that method is defined only on Hash, and ActionController::Parameters is not a Hash.

Comment: @Almaron, nope https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-deep_transform_keys but it only available since Rails 6.0

Comment: Strange. Why did it give an error then.. I'm running 6.0.2.1

Comment: @Almaron I have same error on Rails-6.0.2.1. So I check source code here: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L712 => It means the method is availabe on master branch. But not available for v6.0.2.1 : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.2.1/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb

Comment: Ugly workaround until available: `params.instance_variable_get(:@parameters).deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)`

Comment: I have no idea why it's not working for you guys, but working in my pet project https://github.com/skyderby/skyderby/blob/dev/app/controllers/api/application_controller.rb#L8

Comment: It's not available on [stable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb) for some reason. Will be available in 6.1 (I created an issue [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39081)).

Comment: My bad. You guys are right, I'm wrong. I backported it to my pet project and forgot about it https://github.com/skyderby/skyderby/blob/aea0119a2a94f0a93679372fcbd064e24d50dc3d/config/initializers/params_patch.rb

Answer (score 8):

ActiveSupport already provides a String#snakecase method. All you have to do is install a filter that does a deep iteration through the params hash and replaces the keys with `key.snakecase`.

```
before_filter :deep_snake_case_params!

def deep_snake_case_params!(val = params)
  case val
  when Array
    val.map {|v| deep_snake_case_params! v }
  when Hash
    val.keys.each do |k, v = val[k]|
      val.delete k
      val[k.snakecase] = deep_snake_case_params!(v)
    end
    val
  else
    val
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use string.underscore instead of snakecase

Answer (score 8):

Merging Sebastian Hoitz's answer with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bndkn/4e4b4f4da2c60627eddf), I could make it work on rails 4.2, strong parameters AND parameters wrapping with the [`wrap_parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) tagging method.

I couldn't make it work using a `before_filter`, probably because the parameter wrapping is done before filtering.

In `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`:

```
# Convert json parameters, sent from Javascript UI, from camelCase to snake_case.
# This bridges the gap between javascript and ruby naming conventions.
module ActionController
  module ParamsNormalizer
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def process_action(*args)
      deep_underscore_params!(request.parameters)
      super
    end

    private
      def deep_underscore_params!(val)
        case val
        when Array
          val.map {|v| deep_underscore_params! v }
        when Hash
          val.keys.each do |k, v = val[k]|
            val.delete k
            val[k.underscore] = deep_underscore_params!(v)
          end
          val
        else
          val
        end
      end
  end
end

# Enable parameter wrapping for JSON. You can disable this by setting :format to an empty array.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
  # Include the above defined concern
  include ::ActionController::ParamsNormalizer
end
```

Comment: Your solution was only for POST requests. It is better to change `request_parameters` to `parameters`. In that case it will work for both. I've fix it.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-request_parameters

Answer (score 6):

Solution for **Rails 5**

```
before_action :underscore_params!

def underscore_params!
  underscore_hash = -> (hash) do
    hash.transform_keys!(&:underscore)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      if value.is_a?(ActionController::Parameters)
        underscore_hash.call(value)
      elsif value.is_a?(Array)
        value.each do |item|
          next unless item.is_a?(ActionController::Parameters)
          underscore_hash.call(item)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  underscore_hash.call(params)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't use other suggestions here directly, but it got me on the right track.

With Rails 5.2, using a versioned API and thus unable to change it for the whole application. I created this concern which i then included into the base controller of my new api version module.

```
module UnderscoreizeParams
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def process_action(*args)
    request.parameters.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)
    super
  end
end
```

then in my API V3 BaseController

```
class V3::BaseController
  include UnderscoreizeParams
end
```

enjoy.

Comment: This solution worked best for me, as I wanted to uniformly convert all params keys into underscores from pascalCase / CamelCase(:lower). Some of the other solutions did not handle query string parameters, where this solution does handle query string parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Another rails 5.1 solution that piggy backs off of the Sebastian Hoitz solution above.  To clarify why we need to do this: in R5.1 deep_transform_keys! is no longer a method available to us, since params are no longer inheriting from HashWithIndifferentAccess.  And overcomes the issue mentioned by Eliot Sykes where the initializer only works for application/json mime types.  It does add overhead to all the requests though. (I'd love to see some initializers for `ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:multipart_form]`) though, since the initializer is a better place to be doing this, IMO.

`before_action :normalize_key!`

```
 def normalize_keys!(val = params)
  if val.class == Array
    val.map { |v| normalize_keys! v }
  else
    if val.respond_to?(:keys)
      val.keys.each do |k|
        current_key_value = val[k]
        val.delete k
        val[k.to_s.underscore] = normalize_keys!(current_key_value)
      end
    end
    val
  end
  val
end
```

Answer (score 3):

We are converting our Rails API JSON keys from snake_case to camelCase. We have to do the conversion incrementally, i.e. some APIs work with snake_case while the others change to using camelCase.

Our solution is that we

- create method `ActionController::Parameters#deep_snakeize`
- create method `ApplicationController#snakeize_params`
- set `before_action :snakeize_params` only for the controller actions that handle incoming request with camelCase keys

You can try [vochicong/rails-json-api](https://github.com/vochicong/rails-json-api/commit/008dcea44a2037e2fb074dc3af6ee3ed761b6a00) for a fully working Rails app example.

```
# File: config/initializers/params_snakeizer.rb
# Transform JSON request param keys from JSON-conventional camelCase to
# Rails-conventional snake_case
module ActionController
  # Modified from action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb
  class Parameters
    def deep_snakeize!
      @parameters.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)
      self
    end
  end
end

# File: app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  protected

    # Snakeize JSON API request params
    def snakeize_params
      params.deep_snakeize!
    end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :snakeize_params, only: [:create]

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render :show, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me for porting realworld thinkster rails backend api to version  6.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use Chris Healds version, but since I am using Rails 4 I have strong_parameters enabled so I had to change it up a bit.

This is the version that I came up with:

```
before_filter :deep_underscore_params!


def deep_underscore_params!(val = request.parameters)
  case val
  when Array
    val.map { |v| deep_underscore_params!(v) }
  when Hash
    val.keys.each do |k, v = val[k]|
      val.delete k
      val[k.underscore] = deep_underscore_params!(v)
    end

    params = val
  else
    val
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter that runs before any controller call and apply the following instructions to it:

```
# transform camel case string into snake case
snake_string  = Proc.new {|s| s.gsub(/([a-z])([A-Z])/) {|t| "#{$1}_#{$2.downcase}"}} 

# transform all hash keys into snake case
snake_hash    = Proc.new do |hash| 
  hash.inject({}) do |memo, item|
    key, value = item

    key = case key
          when String
            snake_string.call(key)
          when Symbol
            snake_string.call(key.to_s).to_sym
          else 
            key
          end    

    memo[key] = value.instance_of?(Hash) ? snake_hash.call(value) : value
    memo
  end
end

params = snake_hash.call(params)
```

You must have to consider the above procedure will impose a small overhead on every Rails call.

I am not convinced this is necessary, if it is just to fit in a convention.

Comment: Can also make use of ActiveSupport's underscore method  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore

Comment: @Puhlze Thanks! I didn't know about it.

Comment: There must be a cleaner way to change params hash using underscore method, I'll try to hack something together unless someone beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

tlewin's answer didn't work for me in Rails 3. it seems the params' = operator renders future operations on it void. very strange. anyways the following works for me, as it only uses the []= and delete operators:

```
before_filter :underscore_param_keys
def underscore_param_keys
  snake_hash = ->(hash) {
    # copying the hash for iteration so we are not altering and iterating over the same object
    hash.to_a.each do |key, value|
      hash.delete key
      hash[key.to_s.underscore] = value
      snake_hash.call(value) if value.is_a? Hash
      value.each { |item| snake_hash.call(item) if item.is_a? Hash } if value.is_a? Array
    end
  }
  snake_hash.call(params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ControllerHelper
  before_action :deep_underscore_params!

  def deep_underscore_params!(app_params = params)
    app_params.transform_keys!(&:underscore)
    app_params.each do |key, value|
      deep_underscore_params!(value) if value.instance_of?(ActionController::Parameters)
    end
    app_params.reject! { |k, v| v.blank? }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on Eliot Sykes's answer above, I think we can do a bit better in the Rails5 case. I don't love overwriting that function entirely, since that code could change. So instead I suggest using function composition:

```
# File: config/initializers/json_param_key_transform.rb
# Transform JSON request param keys from JSON-conventional camelCase to
# Rails-conventional snake_case:
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:json] = (
  # Compose the original parser with a transformation
  ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:json] >>
    # Transform camelCase param keys to snake_case
    ->(data) {
      data.deep_transform_keys(&:underscore)
    }
)
```